# Mouse wheel resizes JPanel and all inner components

Tags: java, swing

Let's say I have `JPanel`, `panelA` and two `JButtons` inside it (`button1` and `button2`). I want to add `MouseWheelListener` to `JPanel`, so when I make an event, all components will resize (become larger or smaller). I came up with this code:

```
for (Component comp : panelA.this.getComponents())
{
    if (comp instanceof JButton)
    {
        comp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
            (int) (PREFERRED_WIDTH * SCALE_WIDTH),
            (int) (PREFERRED_HEIGHT * SCALE_HEIGHT)));
    }
}
```

Values of `SCALE_HEIGHT` & `SCALE_WIDTH` are changing when I make an event.

My question is this: is it good? Should I set preferred size all of inner components or make something else?

Answer (score 3):

I was wracking my poor old brain trying to think of way to do this, when it occurred to me that this is a classic case for JXLayer (or [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) under Java 7)

There use to be some really good examples, but they seem to have vanished into the ether

Comment: weirdly true (couldn't find the original examples as well) - just a project that seems to use them: http://code.google.com/p/link-collector/source/browse/ver2/trunk/labs/zoom-with-jxpanel-src/org/pbjar/jxlayer/?r=436 - probably the transformUI

Comment: @kleopatra it's annoying, cause they were awesome

Comment: yeah, but the usage in that project seems to be rather complete - need to check against my local copy (on the other machine, everything we need is always on the other maching, isn't it ;-) Plus Piet Blok had awesome examples in other domains, f.i. treeModels on top of event firing (html) DocumentModels ... from which I have no local copies ... sigh

Comment: @kleopatra Think I "might" have some at work...need sleep first :P